# Is there a tool,, code or setting in Android Studio where you can resize all your images to support multiple screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, the following application resource directories provide different layout designs for different screen sizes and different drawable's. Use the mipmap/ folders for launcher icons.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```

Comment: not directly scaling your drawables, but generates dimensions for other densities...https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify

Comment: There is a plugin called "Android Drawable Importer"

Comment: Can I use the importer like the Windows Paint "color picker?"

Comment: I have installed JetBrains color picker. Is that the one?

Comment: The closest thing to a tool like this is: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html . I'm not familiar with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Material design icon plugin which will help you work with any icons provided by Google : Google material-design-icons and with every resolution.